# Break-up-one-line-of-text-without-any-discernible-break-points-in-php [part 2]

Tags: php, scripting, programming-languages, formatting

I received three really helpful answers here:

[Break up one line of text without any discernible break points in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6662501/break-up-one-line-of-text-without-any-discernible-break-points-in-php/6662591#6662591)

It appeared adding `true` as as option to `wordwrap` fixed the problem but it's breaking another function so badly I can't use it. The function is along the same vein as this issue and grabs long URLs and truncates the anchor text to "Short URL".

Any ideas why the wordwrap `true` addition breaks this ? I see any characters after the set limit of the URL printed after "Short URL" which is quite strange.

```
function long_links($stringa){

$m = preg_match_all('/(www\.|http:\/\/|https:\/\/)([^\s]+)/', $stringa, $match);

 if ($m){ $links=$match[0]; 

      for ($j=0;$j<$m;$j++){

       $loco=$links[$j]; $len=strlen($loco);

         if($len > 59){

        $stringa = str_replace($loco,'<a href="'.$loco.'" title="'.$loco.'" target=_blank><i>Short Link</i></a>',$stringa); 
   } 
  } 
  return $stringa;
 }
```

Why would this break `$body = wordwrap($body, 83, "\n", true); echo $body;` ?

An example of the spill over I see is:

`*Short URL* conditions/products-and-services/bonus-bank/index.htm`

**EDIT following Martin's question**

`$body=long_links($body); $body = wordwrap($body, 83, "\n", true); echo $body;`

Thanks again !

Comment: Where do you call the `long_links()` function (in respect to the `$body =...` line in your question)?

Comment: are you sure that long_links() worked before the addition of the word wrap? and what do you mean by the function is now "broken"?

Comment: Please be so kind and show us the html code of the wrapped long_links.

Comment: Thanks, Martin: `<a href="http://www.vodafone.co.uk/vodafone-uk/about-this-site/terms-and-conditions/products" title="http://www.vodafone.co.uk/vodafone-uk/about-this-site/terms-and-conditions/products" target=_blank><i>Short Link</i></font></a> 
-and-services/bonus-bank/index.htm`. When I swap the order of `long_links` with and `wordwrap` the Short Link still works but all non-short links fail, ie are just text and not "a hrefs".

Comment: Look at my answer, it was too long for a comment, but probably doesn't answer your question 100%...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, have a look at the [wordwrap man page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php). There, in the section *User Contributed Notes* you can find code for a wordwrap function which takes out all html tags, wordwraps the rest and puts the html tags back in.

Then to answer your question, try debugging a bit and share your results by editing your question. What to try:

The provided example should look like this:

```
<a href="http://www.vodafone.co.uk/vodafone-uk/about-this-site/terms-and-conditions/products-and-services/bonus-bank/index.htm" 
   title="http://www.vodafone.co.uk/vodafone-uk/about-this-site/terms-and-conditions/products-and-services/bonus-bank/index.htm" 
   target=_blank><i>Short Link</i></font></a>
```

but looks like this, right?

```
<a href="http://www.vodafone.co.uk/vodafone-uk/about-this-site/terms-and-conditions/products" 
   title="http://www.vodafone.co.uk/vodafone-uk/about-this-site/terms-and-conditions/products" 
   target=_blank><i>Short Link</i></font></a> 
-and-services/bonus-bank/index.htm
```

So, first see what wordwrap does with that:

```
$teststring = '<a href="http://www.vodafone.co.uk/vodafone-uk/about-this-site/terms-and-conditions/products-and-services/bonus-bank/index.htm" 
   title="http://www.vodafone.co.uk/vodafone-uk/about-this-site/terms-and-conditions/products-and-services/bonus-bank/index.htm" 
   target=_blank><i>Short Link</i></font></a>';
echo wordwrap($teststring, 83, "\n", true);
```

If you've done that, please put the html code of the result, as code as it is, into your question.

---

**Try this function (from [the php man page for wordwrap](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.wordwrap.php#103687)):**

*there was code here, but it was of no good quality*

I didn't test it, but if it works, you're lucky, right?

---

**Now you got me to try around a bit and this is my result:**

```
function get_tags_array($str)
{
    //given a string, return a sequential array with html tags in their own elements
    $q = '?';
    return preg_split("/(<.*$q>)/",$str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
}

function html_combi_wordwrap($str, $width = 75, $break = "\n", $cut = false)
{
    $tag_arr = get_tags_array($str);
    foreach($tag_arr as $key => $tag_str)
    {
        if(preg_match("/<.*>/", $tag_str))
            continue;

        $tag_arr[$key] = wordwrap($tag_str, $width, $break, $cut);
    }
    return implode($tag_arr);
}
```

This combines the idea of [this code](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.wordwrap.php#103687) (which is, only wrap text that's no html tags) with the regular wordwrap function which can still be replaced by an utf-8 variant or whatever...

Comment: Thanks for your help, Martin. Your final snippet is exactly what causes your second snippet, if you know what I mean. In other other words your third snippet is exactly what I have and what breaks the Short Link output and causes the spill of text.

Comment: Does this shed any light ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6527880/php-wordwrap-cut-parameter-when-dealing-with-weird-characters

Comment: Thanks, I've tried a few of these from the man page with no luck :(

Comment: @JonathanRoss let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1444/discussion-between-martin-and-jonathan-ross)

Comment: I'll have some time either late today or tomorrow. Thanks again !!